# Flutter ImagePrecache() does not work flutter web

Tags: flutter, image

The Problem:

I want to preload an Image for my flutter web app. The image will be in an **Column()** that is scrolling down. If the image is not preloaded the scrolling effect is stuttering.

What I tried:

I tried to preload the image using **preloadImage()**, it don't work...

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return show
              ? ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height <
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)
                  ? LoginPage(
                      image: Image.asset('assets/design.png'),
                    )
                  : const LoginPage_mobile())
              : const ----();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/dashboard',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const DashboardPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/AGB',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const impressum();
        },
      ),
      
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp.router(
      color: Colors.black,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: _router,
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.white,
        focusColor: Colors.white,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        hintColor: Colors.white,
        hoverColor: Colors.white,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The main is an await function, eventually it is a problem :(

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      ------------------------------
    ),
  );

  
 
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.black,
      focusColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    color: Colors.white,
    title: "",
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}
```